# Why diffrent googlefirebase dynamic link appinstall count and google console install count?

Tags: android, firebase, appinstaller

I use firebase Dynamiclink for app marketing.

and I confirmed that the number of app installs of dynamiclink is 758.
but The number of app installations on the Google Console is far below that.

Is it correct to see Device acquisition in Google Console's Analytics?

why?

I need help :(

[dynamicLink app install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL5Qm.png)

[google console device acquisition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHzwj.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.